# Header checkbox checks gridview rows however interface shows otherwise

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I've got a gridview within an update panel (web forms).  The grid view has a header checkbox so that when you click the header checkbox it checks all item checkboxes below it, like so:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
         <HeaderTemplate>
              <asp:CheckBox ID="HeaderLevelCheckBox" runat="server" 
                onclick="toggleSelection(this);" ToolTip="Select / Deselect all rows?" />
         </HeaderTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelector" runat="server" ToolTip="Select row?" />
         </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Notice the function call `onclick="toggleSelection(this);"` this looks like this:

```
function toggleSelection(source) {
        $("#MainContent_gvCG input[id*='chkSelector']").each(function (index) {
            $(this).attr('checked', source.checked);
            if (source.checked)
                $(this).css({ backgroundColor: "yellow" });
            else
                $(this).css({ backgroundColor: "" });
        });
    }
```

This is declared right after document.ready within a script tag.  When I initially load the page and click the headercheckbox all rows in the gridview are also selected (great...works).  If I uncheck it all rows are unchecked (great works).  The minute I click on it again the UI does not change (all items are not checked like they should be).

I was curious and upon inspecting the markup that too was right, when I click the header to check it to true I get row items that are checked:

`<input id="MainContent_gvCG_chkSelector_5" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvCG$ctl08$chkSelector" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 0);" checked="checked">`

And when I uncheck the header it responds correctly like so:

`<input id="MainContent_gvCG_chkSelector_5" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvCG$ctl08$chkSelector" style="">`

My issue is the UI does not change, meaning the checkboxes do not display as being checked even though the markup shows it as being checked.  Is this due to being inside an updatepanel?

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Try use jQuery **prop** instead of **attr**, it accept bool value instead of attr/removeAttr checked

Comment: @Irvin yea that works `$(this).prop('checked', source.checked);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use jQuery `prop` instead of `attr`, it accepts a boolean value instead of using attr/removeAttr checked attribute.

Code:

```
    function toggleSelection(source) {
        $("#MainContent_gvCG input[id*='chkSelector']").each(function (index) {
            $(this).prop('checked', source.checked);
            if (source.checked)
                $(this).css({ backgroundColor: "yellow" });
            else
                $(this).css({ backgroundColor: "" });
        });
    }
```

Comment: I still don't understand why this worked and why what I did have did not work...but yours works...

Comment: I think because prop works in every situation with boolean values; to add/remove the checked state using attr you must use attr to add and removeAttr to remove the attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this.checked in your javascript

```
    function toggleSelection(source) {
        $("#MainContent_gvCG input[id*='chkSelector']").each(function (index) {
            this.checked = source.checked;
        });
    }
```

or as [Irvin Dominin aka Edward](/users/975520/irvin-dominin-aka-edward) commented

```
    $(this).prop('checked', source.checked);
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes are often tricky since they have multiple modes of changing the value, such as using the keyboard\mouse,etc. I'd recommend the following approach (having used it successfully in production with previous versions of jquery):

```
  $("[id$='chkSelector']").on('change', function () { 
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
      $(this).css({ backgroundColor: "yellow" });
    else
      $(this).css({ backgroundColor: "" });
  });
```

And then in your "Toggle all button", you can trigger the state change:

```
 $("[id$='chkSelector']").each(function (index) {
   $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When u are using `*` it will find all checkboxes which contains `chkSelector` in their id.

Use `$` instead of `*` it will find all chechboxes ending with `chkSelector` in their id.

The controls in gridview will have the `clientid` at the end of the id attribute when they get rendered.

Working with your code:

```
function toggleSelection(source) {
        $("[id$='chkSelector']").each(function (index) { //Use $ here insted of *
            $(this).prop('checked', source.checked);//also use prop instead of attr
            if (source.checked)
                $(this).css({ backgroundColor: "yellow !important" });//also use !important
            else
                $(this).css({ backgroundColor: "" });
        });
    }
```

Comment: why use `!important`? it set to style attribute, so it have  max priority

Comment: may be some style must be ovriding so..i think